# How do I parse a delimited string into columns using only string functions (SQL Server 2008 R2)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I want to parse a delimited string from a database field into multiple columns. The string could have from exactly 0 to 7 components delimited by a special character (char(7) in my particular case). There will not be more than seven components; if there are, they would be ignored and included with delimiter(s) in the last component. **I need to do this without using UDF's or T-SQL.** I don't think the XML parsing functionality is a good fit for this, but I would consider an efficient solution.

That leaves the string manipulation functions. **Since I'm in SQL Server 2008 R2, the string_split() function is not an option.** The brute force approach (below) seems to work, but it's unwieldy and unreadable. I'd be interested in any improvement on it.

```
create table #x (a int, delimited_value varchar(8000))
insert into #x values 
 (1, 'abc')
,(2, 'defgh' + char(7) + 'ij' + char(7) + 'klmnop')
,(3, '')
,(4, 'qr' + char(7) + 's' + char(7) + 't' + char(7) + 'u' + char(7) + 'v' + char(7) + 'w' + char(7) + 'xyz')
,(5, '012' + char(7) + char(7) + '3' + char(7))
,(6, char(7) + char(7) + '4567' + char(7) + char(7) + '89')

select a
,substring(delimited_value, 1, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) - 1) as component1
,substring(delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0) + 1, 8000), isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8001) - isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) - 1) as component2
,substring(delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0) + 1, 8000), isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8001) - isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) - 1) as component3
,substring(delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0) + 1, 8000), isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8001) - isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) - 1) as component4
,substring(delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0) + 1, 8000), isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8001) + 1 ), 0), 8001) - isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) - 1) as component5
,substring(delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0) + 1, 8000), isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8001) - isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) - 1) as component6
,substring(delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value, isnull(nullif(charindex(char(7), delimited_value), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0), 8000) + 1 ), 0) + 1, 8000), 8000) as component7
from #x
```

Comment: Why all the strange requirements? And you can't possibly do this without t-sql, that is the dialect of the sql language that is present in sql server. Your code is unmanageable. Why do you think that XML is not good here? You should try it instead of making assumptions. I am leery of offering any help here because you have a lot of requirements and blocks. Hate to put any effort into something will just get thrown away.

Comment: Well, if you can't use t-sql (which as @SeanLange said is an exceptionally odd, not to mention unworkable requirement), you *can* use CLR. CLR will outperform SQL anyway.

Comment: I simply need an ad hoc type of query into a "hands off" environment. The exact business reasons won't be of interest here. By T-SQL, I mean programming (stored procedures). I did try XML but got illegal character errors on char(7). I'm looking closely at the XML solution below as it seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the requirement not to use a function I am posting a solution that uses one. This is an inline table valued function and is insanely fast. Short of using CLR you aren't going to find a fast splitter out there. You can find the article and the code here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

If you don't like that one there are several other excellent choices here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Using the Jeff Moden splitter (from the first link above) your code would be this simple.

```
select x.a
    , component1 = max(case when y.ItemNumber = 1 then y.Item end)
    , component2 = max(case when y.ItemNumber = 2 then y.Item end)
    , component3 = max(case when y.ItemNumber = 3 then y.Item end)
    , component4 = max(case when y.ItemNumber = 4 then y.Item end)
    , component5 = max(case when y.ItemNumber = 5 then y.Item end)
    , component6 = max(case when y.ItemNumber = 6 then y.Item end)
    , component7 = max(case when y.ItemNumber = 7 then y.Item end)
from #x x
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(x.delimited_value, char(7)) y
group by x.a
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the XML Approach would be easy and efficient solution here.

**Example**

```
Select A.a
      ,B.*
 From  #x A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(delimited_value,char(7),'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

Returns

```
a   Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5    Pos6    Pos7
1   abc     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   defgh   ij      klmnop  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3           NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   qr      s       t       u       v       w       xyz
5   012             3               NULL    NULL    NULL
6                   4567            89      NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I figured you would be post your xml version. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Still a little puzzed with OP's restrictions

Comment: The original issue I had with this, is that it fails if char(6) is included in the data (which it is for me). Change record 2 to this to see what I mean:
,(2, 'de' + char(6) + 'fgh' + char(7) + 'ij' + char(7) + 'klmnop')

Comment: @bvy If you have multiple delimiters 
  ... replace(replace(delimited_value,char(7),'</x><x>'),char(6), '</x><x>')

Comment: char(6) is not a delimiter.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a way to replace it with something legal (and unique) and replace it back later...

Comment: @bvy OK I see what you are saying.  Just tested the char(6) thing.  One moment

Comment: That change with char(6) works fine in the answer I posted. :D